# Where to put other class functions in a hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

say I have a react class component I want to convert to using hooks

```
class Something extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    }

    componentDidMount(){}

    handleSubmit(){}

    changeSomethingElse(){}

    render(){}
}
```

I understand that I can use `useEffect` for `componentDidMount` and `render` and I can use `useState` for my component state but other functions I have in my class, `handleSubmit` in this instance, can that still live as a function inside my new function component or do I need to extract this somewhere else?

Comment: You can have them in your functional component only.

Comment: Just define them as regular function inside your hook function, like here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you extract them somewhere else. In fact, I would argue they almost certainly should never have been part of the class in the first place, and the only reason they are there is because `this` gives you convenient access to props and state. But this convenience comes at a price. The class you gave as an example seems to have the following concerns:

1. Run some logic on mount (GET request?)
2. Handle form submission (POST data?)
3. ChangeSomethingElse (state update?)
4. Render stuff.

That's *a lot* for a single React component. Although I do see a lot of React components like that, they conflate a lot of separate concerns. One of the nice things about functional components is that they make it hard to do this while classes make it oh so easy. Rough translation into a functional component:

```
// easily tested with fetch mocked out, you do
// have to manually pass in data since you don't
// have `this` to get props and state from
const getData = () => {};
const handleSubmit = (evt, data) => {};

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [somethingElse, changeSomethingElse] = useState();

  // Runs once, on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(resp => resp.json()).then(setData);
  }, []);

  return data
    ? <props.RenderComponent data={data} onClick={changeSomethingElse} />
    : <props.LoadingComponent />;
};
```

This component is responsible for state and passing that state on to pure children for rendering. Those functions at the top don't even have to be in the same file if there's no reason for them to go there (unlike the class example). You could even optionally split this into 2-3 components separating the two useState calls and the conditional LoadingComponent render but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
const Something = props => {

  // constructor(){}
  useEffect( () => {      
  }, [])

  // componentDidMount(){}
  useLayoutEffect( () => {      
  }, [])

  // handleSubmit(){}
  const handleSubmit = event => {
  }

  // changeSomethingElse(){}
  const changeSomethingElse = () =>{
  }

  // render() {}
  return (

  )
}
```

Comment: How are you going to test those inner functions?

Comment: Usually it'll be manipulating some state, then my tests will be focused on state changes, not in the function itself.

Comment: That's fair for changeSomethingElse, but 'handleSubmit' sounds a little dicey.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, other functions in a class component will be callback functions that mutate state. They will be passed as event callback (onClick, onChange etc.) or used in timer.

While using hooks, in function component, you will have them as local functions.
If they are using state variables in closure, like `setCounter(counter + 1)`, then you need to create them using `useCallback`, like:

```
const incrCounter = useCallback(() => setCounter(counter + 1))
```

Alternatively, you can use function type param for `setXXX`, in which case you can just declare them as normal local function:

```
const incrConter = () => setCount(counter => counter + 1)
```

If you had other properties in your class component, then you can set them up using `useRef` hook.

Answer (score -2):

i think your concern lies on performance. you can use `useCallback` so that your function wont be recreated on rerender.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'

const Someting = () => {
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {}, [// you can add dependencies here so that the function will be updated with the correct values])
  const changeSomethingElse = useCallback(() => {}, [])

  return <div>do something here...</div>
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @JaredSmith - the answer to his question is obviously `yes` and it is provided on my answer, i did this because i think the OP's is much concern about the performance of having the function recreated on every cycle of the component, that's why i resulted to this